# Tracking in-app purchases & multiple devices (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I want to implement in-app purchases to my app.  I will be using the built-in product model where the IAP will unlock features within the code.  My questions are:

- how do I track the a purchase on a device (as to unlock the feature)?  NSUserDefaults?  The guide vaguely states "application preferences".  They are not referring the Info.plist, as this can't be written once on the device.  I also (obviously) want the user to back this up.
- how do I enable the feature across mutiple devices on the same iTunes account?  Do they have to "purchase" the feature on the other devices, or is there another way?

Thanks and regards,

--John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) NSUSerDefaults is a good solution

2) Use a non consumable product for that http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1

User have to re-buy the product in each device but pay just the first time. A pop up "you've already buy this item" appear and you receive the same receipt.

Comment: Simple enough!!  Thanks for the quick response.  Best regards.